Prove $a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}\ge a+b+c$ given that $abc=1$ $(a, b, c, \in \mathbb{R}^{+})$

Prove $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 \geq a+b+c$ given that $abc = 1$, where $a, b, c, \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

I've tried to use AM-GM to get that $a+b+c \geq 3\sqrt[3]{abc}=3$, and also $a^3+b^3+c^3 \geq 3abc = 3$.
Not sure what to do from here.

fixed :), it says $a, b, c, \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ now

We'd like to use AM-GM to prove $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 \ge a + b + c$, but we don't have the same total degree of $a,b,c$ on both sides. To fix that, we can multiply the right-hand side by $(abc)^{2/3}$, so that now our goal is to prove that $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 \ge a^{5/3} b^{2/3} c^{2/3} + a^{2/3}b^{5/3}c^{2/3} + a^{2/3} b^{2/3} c^{5/3}$.
Now the solution writes itself, because there is only one way to use weighted AM-GM to compare $a^3, b^3, c^3$ to $a^{5/3} b^{2/3} c^{2/3}$: taking weights $\frac59, \frac29, \frac29$, we get $$\frac59a^3 + \frac29b^3 + \frac29c^3 \ge (a^3)^{5/9} (b^3)^{2/9} (c^3)^{2/9} = a^{5/3} b^{2/3} c^{2/3}.$$ If we add this inequality and its cyclic permutations, then the coefficient of each variable on the left is $\frac59 + \frac29 + \frac29 = 1$, so we get $$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 \ge a^{5/3} b^{2/3} c^{2/3} + a^{2/3}b^{5/3}c^{2/3} + a^{2/3} b^{2/3} c^{5/3}.$$
Dividing the right-hand side by $(abc)^{2/3} = 1$, we conclude that $$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 \ge a + b + c.$$

how do you know to take weights $\frac{5}{9},\frac{2}{9},\frac{2}{9}$

We fill in the $?$'s in $(a^3)^{?} (b^3)^{?} (c^3)^{?} = a^{5/3} b^{2/3} c^{2/3}$. (Alternatively, there's Muirhead's inequality, which automates the process.)

also when you say total degree is equal on both sides, do you mean that like the power of $a$ on LHS is 3, while power of $a$ on RHS = $\frac{5}{3} + \frac{2}{3} + \frac{2}{3}=3$

I mean the total degree (degree of $a$ + degree of $b$ + degree of $c$) of each term. Terms like $a^3$, $b^2c$, $abc$, $a^4 b^{-1}$ all have total degree $3$. It's relevant here because AM-GM preserves total degree: it can only relate $a^3 + b^3 + c^3$ to a term of total degree $3$.

do the number of terms have to stay constant, or is that arbitrary

In general, the AM-GM relates a sum of a bunch of terms to a single term. In this specific problem, we end up adding three instances of AM-GM to get a single three-term-to-three-term inequality.

so basically you want to split up one side to get a bunch of terms, and then you use am-gm to get to the other side right

By the power mean inequality,
$$\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}3\geq\left(\frac{a+b+c}3\right)^3.$$
Moreover, you already have by AM-GM that $a+b+c\geq 3$. Therefore
$$a^3+b^3+c^3\geq\frac19(a+b+c)^3\geq a+b+c.$$
